# Perl Loading lines into an array based on contiguous field value

Tags: arrays, perl, csv

Perl Loading lines into an array based on contiguous field value.

I am trying to write a script to iterate through each line of a file and look at the second field. If the second field matches the one after it, push the whole line into an array. Once the second field hits a value that is not the same as the previous one, stop pushing lines into array. 
Then print the array. In the set below most of the lines where the second fields value is PUSA will be skipped over, however the lines where the second field contains the WMCE would be pushed into an array.

```
15:15:07.705 "PUSA17122100vx1m" STE 
15:15:08.709 "PUSA17122100w9sn" STE 
15:50:25.244 "PUSA171221014uk8" STE 
15:50:26.509 "PUSA171221014vpo" STE 
15:50:26.750 "PUSA171221015j7w" STE 
13:58:34.518 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221"  STE 
16:05:31.310 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221"  STE 
16:05:31.310 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221"  STE 
16:05:34.938 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221"  STE 
16:03:35.805 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221"  EOM 
16:03:36.420 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221"  EOM 
15:47:40.061 "PUSA171221015gtm"  STE 
15:47:41.460 "PUSA171221015mmi"  STE 
15:47:45.635 "PUSA17122101536p"  STE 
10:35:50.524 "PUSA171221007k8z"  STE 
10:40:11.406 "PUSA171221007vwl"  STE 
13:51:04.820 "PUSS171221000jpu"  STE 
14:42:50.589 "PUSS17122100193k"  STE 
09:49:53.111 "PUSA171221002a7g"  STE 
13:58:34.562 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221"  STE 
16:05:31.302 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221"  STE 
16:05:31.302 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221"  STE 
16:05:34.931 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221"  STE 
16:03:36.396 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221"  EOM 
16:03:35.859 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221"  EOM 
15:15:06.747 "PUSA17122100w7fw"  STE 
15:15:08.348 "PUSA17122100vrv8"  STE 
15:15:08.542 "PUSA17122100vzhu"  STE
```

This is what I have so far. I have tried saving the second (@$row[1] ) field value and then matching it against the value of the next line. 
But I get these arrays with 2 lines in them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Text::CSV   ;
use Time::Local ;

use strict ;
use warnings ;
my $file = $ARGV[0] ;

open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!" ;


my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({
    binary    => 1,
    auto_diag => 1,
    });
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    print "@$row\n" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to print the lines when two or more consecutive lines have a matching second field.

My solution doesn't require you to look ahead to the next row. Instead the rows are stored to a temporary array, where the last can always be easily matched. Once a non-match or end of input is encountered, the temp array is flushed to output if it contains multiple (matching) items.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV   ;
use Time::Local ;

my $file = $ARGV[0] ;

open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!" ;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary    => 1,
                           auto_diag => 1,
                         });
my @temp_row_storage = ();

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    if (@temp_row_storage  and                    # if we have stored rows; and
        $temp_row_storage[-1][1] ne $row->[1]) {  # the last stored row differs
                                                  # from the current row
        # => print the stored rows if there are at least 2 matching ones
        print(map { "@$_\n" } @temp_row_storage)  if  @temp_row_storage >= 2;

        @temp_row_storage = ();  # empty - these were already printed
    }

    # always store the current row
    push(@temp_row_storage, $row);
}

# cleanup: print the last batch of rows if there were at least 2 matching ones
print(map { "@$_\n" } @temp_row_storage)  if  @temp_row_storage >= 2;
```

Input CSV file:

```
15:15:07.705,"PUSA17122100vx1m",STE
15:15:08.709,"PUSA17122100w9sn",STE
15:50:25.244,"PUSA171221014uk8",STE
15:50:26.509,"PUSA171221014vpo",STE
15:50:26.750,"PUSA171221015j7w",STE
13:58:34.518,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221",STE
16:05:31.310,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221",STE
16:05:31.310,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221",STE
16:05:34.938,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221",STE
16:03:35.805,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221",EOM
16:03:36.420,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221",EOM
15:47:40.061,"PUSA171221015gtm",STE
15:47:41.460,"PUSA171221015mmi",STE
15:47:45.635,"PUSA17122101536p",STE
10:35:50.524,"PUSA171221007k8z",STE
10:40:11.406,"PUSA171221007vwl",STE
13:51:04.820,"PUSS171221000jpu",STE
14:42:50.589,"PUSS17122100193k",STE
09:49:53.111,"PUSA171221002a7g",STE
13:58:34.562,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221",STE
16:05:31.302,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221",STE
16:05:31.302,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221",STE
16:05:34.931,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221",STE
16:03:36.396,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221",EOM
16:03:35.859,"WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221",EOM
15:15:06.747,"PUSA17122100w7fw",STE
15:15:08.348,"PUSA17122100vrv8",STE
15:15:08.542,"PUSA17122100vzhu",STE
```

Output:

```
13:58:34.518 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221 STE
16:05:31.310 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221 STE
16:05:31.310 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221 STE
16:05:34.938 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221 STE
16:03:35.805 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221 EOM
16:03:36.420 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221 EOM
13:58:34.562 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221 STE
16:05:31.302 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221 STE
16:05:31.302 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221 STE
16:05:34.931 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221 STE
16:03:36.396 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221 EOM
16:03:35.859 WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221 EOM
```

EDIT:

If you want to retain/return the quotes around the second field, you can use

```
print(map { qq!$_->[0] "$_->[1]" $_->[2]\n! } @temp_row_storage)
    if  @temp_row_storage >= 2;
```

or

```
print(map { sprintf(qq!%s "%s" %s\n!, @$_) } @temp_row_storage)
    if  @temp_row_storage >= 2;
```

but in both these cases, you must know that each row will contain exactly three fields, for the implementation to work reliably.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. If this is not what you want, please clarify your question

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;
open (IN, $ARGV[0]);

my $prev_row = "";
my @rec;
while (my $row = <IN>) {
    @rec = split(" ", $row);
    if ($prev_row eq "") {
        print "$row" ;
    } else {
        if($rec[1] eq $prev_row) {
            #skip
        } else {
            print "$row";
        }
    }
    $prev_row = $rec[1];
}
```

Output:

```
15:15:07.705 'PUSA17122100vx1m' STE
15:15:08.709 "PUSA17122100w9sn" STE
15:50:25.244 "PUSA171221014uk8" STE
15:50:26.509 "PUSA171221014vpo" STE
15:50:26.750 "PUSA171221015j7w" STE
13:58:34.518 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661535-751d143b2002:171221"  STE
15:47:40.061 "PUSA171221015gtm"  STE
15:47:41.460 "PUSA171221015mmi"  STE
15:47:45.635 "PUSA17122101536p"  STE
10:35:50.524 "PUSA171221007k8z"  STE
10:40:11.406 "PUSA171221007vwl"  STE
13:51:04.820 "PUSS171221000jpu"  STE
14:42:50.589 "PUSS17122100193k"  STE
09:49:53.111 "PUSA171221002a7g"  STE
13:58:34.562 "WMCEQ42PRD_NX:EQ-58661583-a62e3e5ad011:171221"  STE
15:15:06.747 "PUSA17122100w7fw"  STE
15:15:08.348 "PUSA17122100vrv8"  STE
15:15:08.542 "PUSA17122100vzhu"  STE
```

Comment: This does almost the opposite what the OP requested - except for the first "WMCE..." lines being included. (I wasn't the one who downvoted.)